# Transitivity of a relation (unique)

Tags: relations

Okay experts, i do know what the definition of a transitive relation is and how to judge if a relation is transitive or not.But i got across this one question which shouldnt be transitive but the answer in my book says it is .Can someone please tell me how would that be true?

*Consider the set A = {1, 2, 3} and the relation R = {(1, 2), (1, 3)}. R is a
transitive relation.*

Comment: It looks vacuously transitive.  To fail to be transitive, you would have to find pairs $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ with $(a,c)\notin R$, and no such pairs exist.

Comment: is that much enough? i was thinking the same but did not have the faith in my logic.Thanks !

Comment: No problem.  Statements that are vacuously true tend to be unintuitive (and sometimes unsatisfying).    "Every prime number of the form $2^{3n}+1$ with $n>0$ is a counterexample to Fermat's last Theorem" is a true statement because there are no such primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the definition of transitivity says the following: for each $(a,b), (b,c)$ in the relation $R$, we have that $(a,c)$ is an element of the relation.
However, in your case there are no elements $(a,b), (b,c)$, so the relation satisfies the condition to be transitive.

Note that if we would have that $R = \{(1,2), (3,1)\}$, then the relation would not be transitive, since we have that $(3,1), (1,2) \in R$, but $(3,2)$ is not in the relation.

I remember transitivity in the following way: I picture the elements $(a,b)$ of a relation is follows: there is a (directed) arrow from $a$ to $b$. So transitivity means that if there is an arrow from $a$ to $b$ and an arrow from $b$ to $c$, then there is an arrow from $a$ to $c$. The moment you have an arrow from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $c$, but no arrow from $a$ to $c$, the relation is not transitive.

Comment: you just seem so clear in your approach.I visualise things the same way.Is there any way i can specifically ask any question to you everytime i ask something on here ?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I do not think that it is possible to 'send' questions to specific persons...